# signature pad inside listview but not able to draw because of scrolling

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using SfSignaturePad inside listview and i want scrolling but because of scrolling i am not able to draw signature, so Is there any way to stop scrolling for particular area or widget inside listview.

Comment: You have to disable Scrolling in Listview. Show you can use
 physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()in your Listview. and wrap your listview with SingleChildScrollView.

Comment: I have tried but still not working, what I want is disable scrolling gestures for only signature pad

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue, but I've replaced my package with [this signature package](https://pub.dev/packages/signature)
and now I am able to use this signature pad in listview, it is easy to use